# Thunderbird: move Quick Filter Toolbar to main panel

Tags: thunderbird

When I open the "customize" menu in Thunderbird, I can add or remove the items from the toolbar. This way, I can reorder the buttons "write", "reply", "reply all", or remove them altogether.

The Quick Filter Toolbar cannot be moved like this.

There used to be an addon called `quickfiltertoolbar`, which made it possible to move the Quick Filter Toolbar around, same as other items.

I have made a screenshot to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

By default, the Quick Filter Toolbar occupies its own panel, under the main panel. What the addon allowed, was to move the items up to the main panel (purple on my screenshot) and move the various associated buttons as well (attachements, ...)

This way I could save space, and I did not need a separate panel for Quick Filter Toolbar.

Unfortunately, this great addon no longer works with current Thunderbird `68.8`.

I am looking for a way to achive the same, by perhaps using `userChrome.css`, or if not possible by editing the files `omni.ja`.

I have shown on my screenshot what I am trying to achieve.

First, remove the stupid useless buttons from the Quick Filter Toolbar: "Unread", "Starred", "Contact", "Tags".

And then, move the rest up (the pin icon, attachements, and the search field.

Lastly, get rid of the now-empty panel

Can this be achieved ?

Comment: @tukan - I have started another Thunderbird bounty, in case you are interested.

Comment: When I'll be released from kindergarden (my kids), I'll check it out if I can something about it.

Comment: What is this? It looks so different! Is this Windows? Ubuntu?

Comment: @intika - I hope you can find a solution. This has been bothering me for a long time.

Comment: I have found a solution, but it is rather complex so it will take me time to write about it and organized it.

Comment: @intika You wanted it too?  Well I have posted the solution.  I hope you like it.

Comment: @intika thank you ;).  I check out your solution later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited: adding patch script**

The solution is based on the Thunderbird source code.  I have applied these changes for **Thunderbird 68.8.0** (package at Opensuse 68.8.0-1.1 | x86_64) .

You need to unpack the `omni.ja` edit/replace the files the way I have indicated and pack `omni.ja` back again (the same way the path script does).

First what you need to patch is `messenger.xul` file:

```
diff -r chrome\messenger\content\messenger\messenger.xul chrome\messenger\content\messenger\messenger.xul
4798,4824d4797
<     <toolbarbutton id="qfb-sticky" type="checkbox"
<                    class="toolbarbutton-1" orient="horizontal"
<                    crop="none" minwidth="16"
<                    tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.sticky.tooltip;"/>
<     <label id="qfb-results-label"
<            minwidth="&quickFilterBar.resultsLabel.minWidth;"
<            value=""
<            somefmtstring="&quickFilterBar.resultsLabel.some.formatString;"
<            noresultsstring="&quickFilterBar.resultsLabel.none;"/>
<     <textbox is="search-textbox" id="qfb-qs-textbox"
<              align="center"
<              flex="3"
<              class="searchBox"
<              placeholder=""
<              emptytextbase="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.base1;"
<              keyLabelNonMac="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.keyLabel2.nonmac;"
<              keyLabelMac="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.keyLabel2.mac;"
<              timeout="500"
<              maxlength="100"
<              width="170"
<              minwidth="160">
<     </textbox>
<     <toolbarbutton id="qfb-attachment" type="checkbox"
<                    class="toolbarbutton-1" orient="horizontal"
<                    crop="none" minwidth="16"
<                    label="&quickFilterBar.attachment.label;"
<                    tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.attachment.tooltip;"/>
4967a4941
> 
4975c4949
<            defaultset="button-getmsg,button-newmsg,button-chat,button-address,separator,button-tag,separator,qfb-sticky,qfb-results-label,qfb-qs-textbox,qfb-attachment,qfb-show-filter-bar,spring,gloda-search,button-appmenu">
---
>            defaultset="button-getmsg,button-newmsg,button-chat,button-address,separator,button-tag,qfb-show-filter-bar,spring,gloda-search,button-appmenu">
5067c5041,5042
<     <vbox id="quick-filter-bar" hidden="true">
---
> 
>     <vbox id="quick-filter-bar">
5076d5050
<                        hidden="true"
5082c5056
<           <toolbarseparator/>
---
>           <toolbarseparator id="qfb-separator"/>
5085,5086c5059
<                          hidden="true"
<                          align="center"
---
>                          crop="none" minwidth="16"
5090c5063
<            <toolbarbutton id="qfb-starred" type="checkbox"
---
>           <toolbarbutton id="qfb-starred" type="checkbox"
5092d5064
<                          hidden="true"
5099d5070
<                          hidden="true"
5106d5076
<                          hidden="true"
5113d5082
<                          hidden="true"
5122d5090
<                hidden="true"
5129d5096
<                  hidden="true"
```

Notice here the move of the whole section to the mail toolbar section.  Also I have adjusted the values so the search bar is smaller.  Notice that you can simply hide the `quickFilterBar` item by adding `hidden="true"` to the section.  I have added the the hidden tak also to the whole `quickFilterBar` `vbox` as you wished.

Next you need to patch `messageWindow.xul`:

```
diff -r chrome\messenger\content\messenger\messageWindow.xul chrome\messenger\content\messenger\messageWindow.xul
4531c4531
<            defaultset="button-getmsg,button-newmsg,button-chat,button-address,separator,button-tag,separator,qfb-sticky,qfb-results-label,qfb-qs-textbox,qfb-attachment,qfb-show-filter-bar,spring,gloda-search,button-appmenu">
---
>            defaultset="button-getmsg,button-newmsg,button-chat,button-address,separator,button-tag,qfb-show-filter-bar,spring,gloda-search,button-appmenu">
```

Here you want to remain consisten on the messageWindow too.

Next you need to patch `primaryToolbar.css`:

```
diff -r chrome\classic\skin\classic\messenger\primaryToolbar.css chrome\classic\skin\classic\messenger\primaryToolbar.css
479,504d478
< #qfb-sticky {
<   list-style-image: url("chrome://messenger/skin/icons/sticky.svg");
< }
< 
< /*
<  * The coloring based on the matches of the filter is defined at quickFilterBar.js.
<  * It would have to be ported to work within the mail toolbar.
<  *
<  * #qfb-results-label {
<  * color: #4e9a06; // was GrayText
<  * text-align: end;
<  * visibility: hidden;
<  * }
<  * 
<  * #quick-filter-bar[filterActive="matches"] #qfb-results-label {
<  * color: #4e9a06;
<  * }
<  *
<  * #quick-filter-bar[filterActive="nomatches"] #qfb-results-label {
<  * color: #f66;
<  * }
< */
< #qfb-attachment {
<   list-style-image: url("chrome://messenger/skin/icons/attach.svg");
< }
<
```

Adding the the images to `primaryToolbar.css` and also the reference what to do if you want to have different coloring when using the filters.

Last but not the least `quickFilterBar.css`:

```
diff -r chrome\messenger\content\messenger\quickFilterBar.css chrome\messenger\content\messenger\quickFilterBar.css
42c42
<   color: #fff200;  /* was GrayText */
---
>   color: GrayText;
```

The last patching is needed in order for the results to get one nice (yellow) color.  The toolbar was able to differentiate if result was found - green color and not found red. This solution show only one color yellow for both branches.  You would need to migrate the code from the quickFilterBar.js which could prove to be tricky.

**Note:** Please don't forget to delete your profile(s) when applying the changes.

After the changes it looks like this

[image: Quick Filter Toolbar moved to the main panel]

### A patch for linux

As promised I'm now adding a direct patch file for the changes (Using sed (GNU sed) 4.8): [Thunderbird quick filter widgets move to main toolbar - patch](https://github.com/tukanos/scripts/blob/master/thunderbird-widgets_move-patch).  This patch patches the move only (not including the previous patches).

**Edit2:**

If you need for the quick filter search buttons (`Sender`, `Recipients`, `Subject`, `Body`) to appear you need to comment out this sed:

```
# hiding the whole box
sed -E -i -e 's:(\s*<\w+\s\w+="quick-filter-bar")(>):\1 hidden="true"\2:' chrome/messenger/content/messenger/messenger.xul
```

After commenting out, you need to active `quick search toolbar` again.  This will show a black line, the `quick search toolbar` itself without buttons.  The filter buttons (`Sender`, `Recipients`, `Subject`, `Body`) will then appear when a filter string is entered.

Comment: thank you. But I am having difficulties patching the 4 files. Looks like you are using windows, and the files here have slight differences. Also, I have custom modifications in `messenger.xul` and `messageWindow.xul` from my previous bounty. So I cannot simply copy your files. I have uploaded my files here: https://www37.zippyshare.com/v/fHVREc2N/file.html

Comment: @400theCat I have now added a direct patch file with which you can patch your omni.ja file directly.  Some of the `sed` (check the version) were tricky, but I have now tested it and it works as it should.  Yes, the original files posted were for windows.  I want to have patched both versions.

Comment: your script seems to work nicely, it patches the files successfully. But when I then start Thunderbird with the new `omni.ja`, the changes don't look as expected. The `Quick Filter Toolbar` disappeared completely, but neither quick filter , nor the `pin` and `attachment` appear on the main panel. So basically same as if I simply removed Quick Filter Toolbar altogether.  You can try running the sed command on the files I have uploaded above (pre-script). Or I can upload the files after I ran your script. Sorry for the trouble. I see you have put a lot of work into this.

Comment: oh, and I assume by `Please don't forget to delete your profile(s) when applying the changes`, you meant delete my `~/.cache/thunderbird/<profile>/`, not the actual profile in `~/.thunderbird/<profile>/`.

Comment: wait. I think it works. I just had to add the items using the "customize" menu. I am testing now if everything works as expected.

Comment: @400theCat It certainly was lot of work :).  When I was developing it I was deleting both profiles to make sure everything was vanilla.  After applying the patch everything should be visible rightaway.

Comment: I did not delete my profile, so I had to add those items from the "customize" menu manually. Another thing, I don't understand what you are trying to do with changing the text color. Now after the changes, the text is on the right from the quick filter textfield, instead on the left. Is this intentional? Is it possible to move it back left, so that the text f=iled is next to the "Attachment" icon? Also, I have now realized I don't want the pin icon at all. Which sed command can I ignore if I don't want it? I made a screenshot: https://paste.pics/b6df6009e0eec470061dd75072cb155e

Comment: @400theCat Changing the text color after the search I'm trying to tell the user (you) that the functionality has changed (there is no more green(found)/red(not found)) differentiation as it was before.  Otherwise, it could be rather confusing, why it is green when it did not find anything.  You can change it to whatever color suits you. After the patching the text position should appear on the left side of the search field (as you can see on my screenshot). It probably has to do something with you using the `customize` option.

Comment: @400theCat if you do not want the `pin` button you can ignore this part of the sed command (just remove it): `<toolbarbutton id="qfb-sticky" type="checkbox" class="toolbarbutton-1" orient="horizontal" crop="none" minwidth="16" tooltiptext="&quickFilterBar.sticky.tooltip;"/>` and you have to remove the `qfb-sticky` from the first `sed` command.

Comment: thank you. Everything works now. You are a genius.

Comment: actually, one more thing: before, when I used the quick filter, when I started typing, the panel expanded by a second line, which contained: `Filter messages by:  Sender Recipient Subject Body`. This now no longer works. I guess because we removed the original panel. Is there any chance to get this functionality back? The quick filter is pretty much useless, if you cannot choose to search `sender`, `recipient`, `Subject`. I would be happy to open new bounty, if you know how to fix this. I can also provide screenshot, it it is not clear what I mean.

Comment: @400theCat You are welcome.  I'm glad it worked out for you.  While I would love to be a genius, I only put the required work for code searching and made the changes.  It got me interested and as I plan to use Thunderbird, I'll use the patches myself too (little bit modified).  It is fascinating how the old addons will disappear but there are no new ones to replace them (for this modification it will be tricky to make an addon).

Comment: @400theCat I think I know what you mean, but screenshot will be the best.  I'll have to check the source code to see how it behaves and if it can be brought back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108576/discussion-between-400-the-cat-and-tukan).

Comment: Again, why down-voting without any comment?  This solution was tested and is working!

Comment: Who is downvoting? I can vouch for the solution. I spent 1000 bounty, accepted the answer, and I am happy with the result.